# How to update users settings.json in vscode with extension packs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've developed a `vscode extension` [VSCodeWebDeveloperExperiencePack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SeyyedKhandon.vscode-web-developer-experience), Now I'm facing the conflicting between some of them, like `turbo console` and `deploy`, I wrote a manual for the configuration on the extension page, as you can see in below:

#### Pre-defined settings which you maybe want to use:

1. press `ctrl+shift+p`
2. type `settings`
3. click on `Prefrences: Open settings (JSON)` to open your settings.json file
4. add these lines of settings:

```json
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Atom One Dark",
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
  "editor.fontLigatures": "",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.fontSize": 16,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "sync.gist": "70a5fe700fe4e46aebdf678a5c1db398",
  "typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
  "local-history.exclude": [
    "**/.history/**",
    "**/.vscode/**",
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/typings/**",
    "**/out/**",
    "**/Code/User/**"
  ]
```

Also, there are some `keybindings` configs like below:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+l",
    "command": "bookmarks.jumpToNext",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "-bookmarks.jumpToNext",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+k",
    "command": "extension.deploy.listen"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+l",
    "command": "-extension.deploy.listen"
  }
]
```

But I want to make it possible or show the user a choice to select `configure automatically`, which on click on it, or on installing the extension, it put the desiered config to user's settings.json.

I read [VScode](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configuration) , but couldn't fix the problem, for example I did add this to my ext-pack `package.json`:

```json
  "contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "title": "VsCode Web Developer Experience",
      "properties": {
        "editor.fontSize": {
          "type": "number",
          "default": 22,
          "description": "this will changes the font settings"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?

Comment: @Sebastian yes, i've updated the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved this problem based on vscode docs, here is an example which you can use:

1. Put this in `package.json` [zpack-package.json](https://github.com/seyyedkhandon/zpack/blob/master/package.json):

```
 "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "zpack.updateConfig",
        "title": "Update Essentials Web Extension Pack (ZPack series) Config"
      }
    ]
  },
```

2. Use this for triggering the action [zpack-extension.ts](https://github.com/seyyedkhandon/zpack/blob/master/src/extension.ts):

```js
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { extractAsKeyValue, GeneralObject } from "./util";
import { defaultSettings } from "./defaultSettings";

const updateUserSettings = async (settings: GeneralObject[]) => {
  settings.forEach(async setting => {
    const { key, value } = extractAsKeyValue(setting);
    await vscode.workspace
      .getConfiguration()
      .update(key, value, vscode.ConfigurationTarget.Global);
  });
};
export async function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  console.log(
    'Congratulations, your extension "Essentials Web Extension Pack (ZPack series)" is now active!'
  );
  let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand(
    "zpack.updateConfig",
    async () => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(defaultSettings, null, 1));
      await updateUserSettings(defaultSettings);
      await vscode.window.showInformationMessage(
        "ZPack Config has been updated"
      );
    }
  );
  context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

export function deactivate() {}
```